# How to install R package in ubuntu 14.04.03?

Tags: 14.04, package-management, updates, r

As per the documentation given on the page 
http://ftp.iitm.ac.in/cran/

I tried to install the latest R package v3.2.2 on my system(32-bit).

I have added

```
deb http://cran.rstudio.com/ubuntu trusty/

deb-src http://cran.rstudio.com/ubuntu trusty/
```

in package source list but when i run

`sudo apt-get update`

command the update gets failed for the newly added sources.

```
Fetched 1,384 kB in 42s (32.4 kB/s)
W: Failed to fetch http://cran.rstudio.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://cran.rstudio.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

How to install the v3.2.2 package on my system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/, the correct url seems to be

```
deb https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu trusty/
```

The information on your page seems to be outdated.

Edit: In order to install packages from this repository, you'll need to add the public key they're signed with. Most conveniently, this is done with the following command:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E084DAB9
```

This is also described in the link above. If this procedure does not work, please read the point [Secure APT](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/#secure-apt)

Comment: After modifying the sources.list with the mentioned "deb https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu trusty/" and then perform the sudo apt-get update, i am getting the following error: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 51716619E084DAB9. How to resolve the error? It seems that my network firewall is blocking this port for access, but how to resolve it?

Comment: You need to add the public key of this repository. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: After getting the key using
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E084DAB9
when did the sudo apt-get update , while updating the index for 
https://cran.rstudio.com trusty/ , i am getting the timeout error.

Comment: I am getting the following error while running the apt-get update 

Err https://cran.rstudio.com trusty/ Packages
  Connection timed out after 120001 milliseconds
W: Failed to fetch https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu/trusty/Packages  Connection timed out after 120001 milliseconds

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Even i have very good internet connection.

Comment: Finally the solution worked. Now able to install the v3.2.2 R package . Thanks.